# React : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, yup

I have the following component. The onSubmit method is called

```
export const LoginForm = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const onSubmit = (values, actions) => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `localhost:3000/api/accounts/login`,
            data: values,
            headers: {
            'CONTENT-TYPE': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
            setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            actions.setFieldError('general', 'Something went wrong');
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
                .email('Must be a valid email')
                .max(255)
                .required('Email is required'),
            password: Yup.string()
                .max(255)
                .required('Password is required')
        })}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
}
```

I'm getting the following message in the console and don't know hoe exactly to fix it

```
    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
        in LoginForm (at routes.js:43)
        in Outlet (at MainLayout/index.js:40)
        in div (at MainLayout/index.js:39)
        in div (at MainLayout/index.js:38)
        in div (at MainLayout/index.js:37)
        in div (at MainLayout/index.js:36)
        in MainLayout (at routes.js:41)
```

I'm not using the `useEffect` hook so I don't know what is happening

Comment: `setLoading(false);` might be called when formik is unmounted, bacause of navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, the message may be a bit confusing since you aren't using the `useEffect` hook, but the issue of attempting to update state *after* the component unmounted isn't strictly limited to `useEffect`. Any asynchronously processed code can induce this error. My guess would be the state update that is enqueued right after the imperative navigation is issued. You navigate to another route and this `LoginForm` component is then umounted.

I think you can remove the `setLoading(false);` when navigating away from the page.

```
const onSubmit = (values, actions) => {
  setLoading(true);

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `localhost:3000/api/accounts/login`,
    data: values,
    headers: {
      'CONTENT-TYPE': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
      navigate('/', {
        replace: true
      });
      // remove the state update that was here
    })
    .catch(error => {
      actions.setFieldError('general', 'Something went wrong');
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, by removing the setLoading(false)  from finally block the issue is gone. thanks